# Rocky Linux 8 : DH Key configuration issues with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, openssl, centos8

My NodeJS Application/Code is working good with CentOS 7. After porting (Compile & Deploy) the same code base on “Rocky Linux 8” System, I am getting below error.

Note : AWS API Gateway is having this backend system

> Error :  {“name”:“oscError”,“message”:“write EPROTO
> 139715211144128:error:141A318A:SSL routines:tls_process_ske_dhe:dh key
> too
> small:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:2150:\n”,“loggerTraceId”:“6ccceae0-03dc-11ec-a840-ad029ce146b1”,“logger”:{},“type”:“GatewayTimeout”}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the TLS client doesn't like the DH params presented by the server. In particular, the DH key size is too small. See the [openssl security levels](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/SSL_CTX_get_security_level.html) which are configured through `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`.

You need to amend either server or client configuration. I presume this is the server that is configured with weak DH parameters, not the client expecting exceptionally strong security.

Comment: I dont have control over server end to upgrade DH/Security levels, where as I tried to change client configuration to accept weak DH parameter. Dont know why It dint work.

I used below security configuration on /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf (Over Rocky Linux 8)
[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.0
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1

Comment: What does the server respond with? SECLEVEL=1 won't help if it responds with DH group 1, i.e. 768-bit.

Comment: Have not seen any such out put over curl -vv command. 
Also when I used --cipher 'DEFAULT:!DH'  , In that case also issue was same over client end.